# BufferedReader gives null when file is not in Documents

Tags: java, swing, io

I am working on a text editor software(kinda like notepad) and whenever I open files from Documents, correct data is displayed but at any other location `Null` is returned
[image: Image contains code and notepad picture]

Comment: check the path in the debugger

Comment: On a side note, use StringBuilder rather than doing string concatenation in a loop

Comment: When you open your application get the current working directory. `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Comment: Is it too hard to post your code, instead of an image partially occluded?

Comment: Code is text and should be added as well formatted/indented **text** in questions. Using images is discouraged! You dont need to take a screen shot in order to tell us which line returns **null**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `bff.readLine()` is returning null. According to the documentation, it returns null if the end of the stream has been reached.

The previous check `bff.readLine() != null` doesn't help, because each call advances the reader. Try it like that:

```
 String line;
  while ((line = bff.readLine()) != null) {
      sk += line + "\n";
}
```